# Firebase Remote Config results on initial request

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm using a singleton to fetch the parameters from a Firebase remote config file. The first time the app is run, I can only access the default values from the singleton; subsequent runs correctly return the config's values. What's a better way to do this, so I can access the values from a fresh start?

```
protocol RemoteConfigProtocol {
    func remoteConfigReceived()
}

class RemoteConfigManager {

    static let sharedInstance = RemoteConfigManager()
    var delegate: RemoteConfigProtocol?

    let demoTitle: String

    // private initialiser for the singleton
    private init() {
        // Configure for dev mode, if needed
        let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
        #if DEBUG
            let expirationDuration: TimeInterval = 0
            remoteConfig.configSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)!
        #else
            let expirationDuration: TimeInterval = 3600
        #endif

        // default values
        let appDefaults: [String: NSObject] = [
            "demo_title": "Default Title" as NSObject
        ]
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(appDefaults)

        // what exactly does "activeFetched" do, then?
        remoteConfig.activateFetched()

        // set the values
        self.demoTitle = remoteConfig["demo_title"].stringValue!

        // this seems to prep app for subsequent launches
        remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration) { status, _ in
            print("Fetch completed with status:", status, "(\(status.rawValue))")
            self.delegate?.remoteConfigReceived()
        }
    }
}
```

When the asynchronous `fetch` command returns in the code above (presumably with the parameter values), I am still unable to access these values coming from the config file. Only upon subsequent runs of the app are they there. Why is that? Am I missing something in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call activateFetched() *after* the fetch completes.  Right now, you're calling it *before* the fetch even starts.  Fetched config parameters will not be available to your app until you call activateFetched().

Comment: Yes! With the addition my variables need to be reset after this point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With @doug-stevenson's answer, this is the code to fetch config parameters, and use them immediately:

```
protocol RemoteConfigProtocol {
    func remoteConfigReceived()
}

class RemoteConfigManager {

    static let sharedInstance = RemoteConfigManager()
    var delegate: RemoteConfigProtocol?

    var demoTitle: String

    // private initialiser for the singleton
    private init() {
        // Configure for dev mode, if needed
        let remoteConfig = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()
        #if DEBUG
            let expirationDuration: TimeInterval = 0
            remoteConfig.configSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)!
        #else
            let expirationDuration: TimeInterval = 3600
        #endif

        // default values
        let appDefaults: [String: NSObject] = [
            "demo_title": "Default Title" as NSObject
        ]
        remoteConfig.setDefaults(appDefaults)

        // set the values from the defaults
        self.demoTitle = remoteConfig["demo_title"].stringValue!

        // fetch the new values
        remoteConfig.fetch(withExpirationDuration: expirationDuration) { status, _ in
            print("Fetch completed with status:", status, "(\(status.rawValue))")

            // activate the newly fetched values
            remoteConfig. activateFetched()

            // reset my variables
            self.demoTitle = remoteConfig["demo_title"].stringValue!

            // tell my view controller to update the UI
            self.delegate?.remoteConfigReceived()
        }
    }
}
```